# How to set a time using php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

This is newbie question when set a time in my form exactly
But When I retrieve data from database The formation of time is not correct..

```
    <?php

include ('includes/config.php');



$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_UNAME,DB_PASSWD,DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){

    throw new Exception($mysqli->connect_error, $mysqli->connect_errno);

}



if(isset($_POST['addbtn'])){

$time= date("h:iA");
$tqry = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_time(table_time.time) VALUES (?) ");

if(!$tqry){

    throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
}
$tqry->bind_param('s', $time);
$tqry->execute();


}
```

The result is the same on my system clock but +1hr advance
why?
thanks in advance..

Comment: set you default timezone , i guess its server time

Comment: You can make use of the built-in [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function and make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Everyone....
Sorry for this newbie question....

Answer (score 0):

set your default time zone in top of your php script , see it might solves your issue

eg,

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

ref: https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set

Answer (score 0):

If your web server and database server are going to be in the same region(if its going to be in cloud) then you can use inbuilt function of MySql Now() to store time otherwise you must set default timezone on the top of your php script.

Note : best way to avoid such type of problems is store the timestamp values in int and convert them in appropriate format when display.

For example :

```
 // store  
    table_time = time();
 // show in php 
    date('h:iA',table_time)
```